# UK Registered car, French insurance

Tags: united-kingdom, france, vehicle-registration, car-insurance

We have recently purchased a new/second-hand Audi from the UK and are in the process of re-registering it in France where we have lived for he past 10 years (My husband is Irish and I am British). We have changed the lights, obtained the certificate of conformity, are awaiting the control technique and of course it is French insured. However, it is necessary to return to the UK briefly (2 nights) for a family wedding and I am concerned at the current legal status of the vehicle for the journey. Does anyone have experience of this situation should we be stopped by the police in the UK?

Comment: I don't have a direct answer to your question, unfortunately, but I'm in the process of bringing my car over the France, and wonder how hard it was to get insurance on it France before it's registered (i.e. before I get my carte gris).  As for your situation it sounds tricky...I might consider just renting a car for your brief return as it might be less headache.